# Prove that a convergent sequence is bounded

Tags: analysis

> Prove that a convergent sequence in a metric space is bounded.

I know this is a basic question, but there is a reasonable propablity that this will come up on my exams and I messed this proof up in my homework, because I was too informal. Is this attempt correct?

Let $a_n$ denote a convergent sequence in a metric space and $a$ its limit. By definition this means that for any $\epsilon>$, $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ there is a $N$, $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n$ , $n \in \mathbb{N}$ larger than $N$ we have that $d(a_n,a)<\epsilon$. Let $\epsilon=1$. Thus we find such a $N$ such that for every $n\geq N$ we have $d(a_n,a)<1$. For $n < N$ we also find $d(a_n,a) \leq \max \{d(a_1,a),...,d(a_{N-1},a)\}$. If we combine the two inequalities we find for any $n$ that $d(a_n,a) \leq R$ with $R:=1+\max \{d(a_1,a),...,d(a_{N-1},a)\}$. This implies virtually by definition that $a_n$ is bounded. $\square$

Comment: Your proof is fine. $(a_n)$ is a sequence, not a series.

Comment: I see... I'm going to edit it

Comment: ok ty for reading

Comment: The second sentence is a restatement of the definition, and can be removed.

Comment: The problem with your proof is the red part in the following: 

*For $n < N$ we also find $d(a_n,a) \leq \max \{d(a_1,a),...,d(a_{\large{\color{red}{n}}-1},a)\}$.*

Comment: ups i understand